# How to delete listview items with an alert dialog

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I have tried many different methods, but non of them work with my code. I know how to make an Alert Dialog, but whenever I put it in my MainActivity, I have a bunch of error I can't seem to fix. Maybe I am putting it in the wrong place...or typos? I don't know, here is my MainActivity, the code runs perfectly. How would I go about putting an Alert Dialog in there, that deletes a ListView item when the user clicks yes? Thank you.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText et;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    Button btn;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        LoadPreferences();
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String task = et.getText().toString();


                adapter.add(task);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                SavePreferences("LISTS", task);
            }
        });}

    protected void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();


    }

    protected void LoadPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String dataSet = data.getString("LISTS", " ");

        adapter.add(dataSet);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Here is the Alert Dialog I am trying to use:

```
@Override 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int position, long id) {

    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Hello My Name is");
    alertDialog.setMessage("" + mNameList.get(position));
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setButton2("Remove", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Removed from list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

And I am trying to put it right under:

```
adapter.add(task);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            SavePreferences("LISTS", task);
        }
    });}
```

Is that where it's supposed to go?

Comment: Post the error please

Comment: There is no error in this code, I just don't know how to make an alert dialog that deletes a listview item, or else almost all the words turn red with errors.

Comment: You said "whenever I put it in my MainActivity, I have a bunch f error I can't seem to fix. ". Where are the errors?

Comment: Post your AlertDialog code as well.

Comment: @MobileDeveloper Ok I posted the AlertDialog code.

Comment: Can you also post the errors as requested by others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this you'd want to:

- Get the string that you're wanting to remove
- Remove it from the string array that's used to populate the ListView
- Update the ListView with the new contents of the string.

  ```
  // Make the app remove an entry if the user "LONG CLICKS" the entry
      if (listViewList != null) {
          listViewList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                  String strTemp = listViewList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                  Toast.makeText(CustomListActivity.this, "Removed " + strTemp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  strWords.remove(position);
                  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(CustomListActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_list, strWords);
                  listViewList.setAdapter(adapter);
                  return false;
              }
          });
      }
  ```

This example is used in a different situation, it's from an app that I have made recently - although slightly cut down so you only see what you need to.  It's very easy to adapt to work with an alert dialog.

Comment: Give me a few mins I'll jump on pc and edit with some code :)

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot, I have been trying to figure this out all day, lol. :)

Comment: @RedJunior good, glad I could help, if it's solved please mark this as the answer :)